# Does every non-empty set admit a group structure (in ZF)?

Tags: set-theory, gr.group-theory, lo.logic, axiom-of-choice

It is easy to see that in ZFC, any non-empty set $S$ admits a group structure: for finite $S$ identify $S$ with a cyclic group, and for infinite $S$, the set of finite subsets of $S$ with the binary operation of *symmetric difference* forms a group, and in ZFC there is a bijection between $S$ and the set of finite subsets of $S$, so the group structure can be taken to $S$. However, the existence of this bijection needs the axiom of choice.

So my question is

> Can it be shown in ZF that for any non-empty set $S$ there exists a binary operation $\ast$ on $S$ making $(S,\ast)$ into a group?

Comment: You should edit your LaTeX a bit. Also, I don't understand what you mean by a bijection between $S$ and its finite subsets - when $S$ is finite, doesn't Cantor's theorem that $|S|<|P(S)|$ mean this isn't the case?

Comment: @Zev: you're right, I've edited the question.

Comment: If it could be so shown, wouldn't the group identity give you a choice function?

Comment: @David: if $S$ is non-empty, I can take an element $s_0$ from $S$, and define an operation $x\ast y=s_0$ for all $x,y\in S$. This gives me a semigroup on $S$, and can be done without the axiom of choice.

Comment: There is a canonical way of turning a semigroup into a monoid (basically just by adding a forced identity element, which if $S$ is infinite, shouldn't change the cardinality). Since the resulting monoid $M$ is commutative (Konrad's original semigroup is commutative), we have that $M\times M/\sim$ is a group (where, if I am stating this correctly, $(a,b)\sim(c,d)$ if there is a $k\in M$ with $adk=bck$). I don't know enough about cardinalities - can we guarantee that $M\times M/\sim$ will have the cardinality of $M$ (i.e. the cardinality of $S$)?

Comment: Zev, turning Konrad's semigroup into a monoid gives you the trivial monoid, since x*1 = x = s_0 for all x.

Comment: Ah, right - good call.

Comment: Also, the techniques mentioned in the following question look related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/6262/does-every-set-admit-a-rigid-binary-relation-and-how-is-this-related-to-the-axi

Comment: @David: You don't get a choice function so easily, because of course there will generally be *many* group structures on the set, and you'd have to choose the group structure, before using your idea to "choose" the identity.

Answer (score 174, accepted):

In ZF, the following are equivalent:

(a) For every nonempty set there is a binary operation making it a group

(b) Axiom of choice

Non trivial direction [(a) $\to$ (b)]:

The trick is Hartogs' construction which gives for every set $X$ an ordinal $\aleph(X)$ such that there is no injection from $\aleph(X)$ into $X$. Assume for simplicity that $X$ has no ordinals. Let $\circ$ be a group operation on $X \cup \aleph(X)$. Now for any $x \in X$ there must be an $\alpha \in \aleph(X)$ such that $x \circ \alpha \in \aleph(X)$ since otherwise we get an injection of $\aleph(X)$ into $X$. Using $\circ$, therefore, one may inject $X$ into $(\aleph(X))^{2}$ by sending $x \in X$ to the $<$-least pair $(\alpha, \beta)$ in $(\aleph(X))^{2}$ such that $x \circ \alpha = \beta$. Here, $<$ is the lexicographic well-ordering on the product $(\aleph(X))^{2}$. This induces a well-ordering on $X$.

Comment: Fantastic! This is a great argument! It is just equivalent to AC.

Comment: Aha, very neat!

Comment: Ashutosh, is this your argument? I want to use it and give proper credit.

Comment: I had heard this problem from a friend. We were trying to determine the possible sizes (cardinal types) of groups in a choice free world and ended up with something of this kind.  I'm sure it's a folklore result but cannot be sure. I'll try asking him.

Comment: I did some googling and found this:

Hajnal, A., Kertész, A. - Some new algebraic equivalents of the axiom of choice, Publ. Math. Debrecen 19 (1972), 339--340 (1973).

Review on MathSciNet:

The authors show that in ZF, the axiom of choice is equivalent to the statement: on every nonempty set there exists a cancellative groupoid.

Comment: Is it the same proof? My personal subscription to Publ. Math. Debrecen here at home unfortunately runs out in 1971...

Comment: I don't know. I cannot access that paper either.

Comment: I think this proof is Hajnal and Kertesz'. Some indirect evidence via Google: in these lecture notes on set theory on the web (in German) http://users.math.uni-potsdam.de/~raesch/logik/Seminarbericht.pdf on pages 36-37 the same proof occurs. The only reference there is to the paper of Hajnal and Kertesz. Somebody with access to this paper out there?

Comment: I have it. Same proof. 

Comment: Hajnal now loaded his paper with Kertesz to Reseacrhgate, so it's available: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266924213_Some_new_algebraic_equivalents_of_the_axiom_of_choice

Answer (score 29):

You cannot in general put a group structure on a set. There is a model of ZF with a set A that has no infinite countable subset and cannot be partitioned into finite sets; such a set has no group structure.

See e.g at http://groups.google.com/group/sci.math/msg/06eba700dfacb6ed

---

Sketch of proof that in standard Cohen model the set $A=\{a_n:n\in\omega\}$ of adjoined Cohen reals cannot be partitioned into finite sets:

Let $\mathbb{P}=Fn(\omega\times\omega,2)$ which is the poset we force with. The model is the symmetric submodel whose permutation group on $\mathbb{P}$ is all permutations of the form $\pi(p)(\pi(m),n)=p(m,n)$ where $\pi$ varies over all permutations of $\omega$, (that is we are extending each $\pi$ to a permutation of $\mathbb{P}$ which I also refer to as $\pi$) and the relevant filter is generated by all the finite support subgroups.

Suppose for contradiction that $p\Vdash " \bigcup_{i\in I}\dot{A_i}=A$ is a partition into finite pieces"; let $E$ (a finite set) be the support of this partition. Take some $a_{i_0}\not\in E$ and extend $p$ to a $q$ such that $q\Vdash ``\{a_{i_0},\ldots a_{i_n}\}$ is the piece of the partition containing $a_{i_0}$". Then pick some $j$ which is not in $E$ nor the domain of $q$ nor equal to any of the $a_{i_0},\ldots a_{i_l}$. If $\pi$ is a permutation fixing $E$ and each of $a_{i_1},\ldots a_{i_n}$ and sending $a_{i_0}$ to $a_j$, it follows that $\pi(q) \Vdash " \{a_j,a_{i_1},\ldots a_{i_n}\}$ is the piece of the partition containing a_j". But also $q$ and $\pi(q)$ are compatible and here we run into trouble, because $q$ forces that $a_{i_0}$ and $a_{i_1}$ are in the same piece of the partition, and $\pi(q)$ forces that this is not the case (and they are talking about the same partition we started with because $\pi$ fixes $E$). Contradiction.

Comment: Justin, it would be kind of you to sketch the proof of Randall's point (3) in the link. 

Comment: do you mean how to get a model with an A satisfying (3)?

Comment: Yes. I am clear on the usual symmetric name forcing argument for getting (1) and (2). And Dougherty suggests it is the same for (3), so I was wondering if you could give a quick sketch for the set theorists. (Otherwise, I'll just think it through myself.)

Comment: Ok, I added a sketch (which initially was incorrect but I have edited it appropriately)

Comment: This gives a good intuition of what is possible in ZF. And the link shows that my question came up in a discussion on sci.math in 2003....

Comment: Justin, I discussed this topic with a friend which explained that unbounded amorphous can have a group structure. In fact, Lauchli's construction of a vector space can be made amorphous if the underlying field is finite, resulting a vector space that every subset if either a subset of a finitely dimensional subspace (hence finite under the assumption the field is finite), or the set complement of such finitely dimensional subspace. Thus every set is finite or co-finite. Since vector spaces are also abelian groups...

Comment: Hm...I am not familiar with the Lauchli construction. But I see no error in the argument given at sci.math link. Do you?

Comment: No, but note several things: (1) The Dedekind-finite set of reals cannot be amorphous since amorphous set cannot be linearly ordered. (2) They use the condition that any partition cannot have more than finitely many non-singletons. If an amorphous set satisfies condition (2) it is called *strongly* amorphous, if this $n$ is bounded then it is bounded-amorphous (or $n$-amorphous) and otherwise unbounded. For Lauchli's construction I gave a quick overview in my answer on Konrad's other question about trivial duals.

Comment: Justin, I think that the StackExchange platform is to correct it until it's perfect. Since I cannot (and would not) edit your answer to correct the aforementioned mistakes please make the effort to correct this for yourself (the set is not amorphous but rather Dedekind-finite, and unbounded amorphous sets can be given a group structure, in fact it would be an infinite group that every [proper] subgroup is finite). Thanks!

Comment: I was confused about your comments but I see the issue now. The definition of amorphous does not include condition (3) (not being able to be partition into finite sets). And obviously the adjoined set of Cohen reals is not an amorphous set. I'll just remove reference to amorphous sets from my answer since it doesn't seem relevant.

Comment: Thanks! It can be confusing sometimes, I know that I make these sort of mistakes more often than I'd like to. The important thing is that it is now corrected! :-)