# Does every non-empty set admit an (affine) scheme structure (in ZFC)?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, set-theory

This question is partially inspired by this question: *[Does every non-empty set admit a group structure (in ZF)?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/12973/12218)*

It was also inspired by my desire to explain the importance of quotient morphisms when discussing algebraic quotients.  I wanted to point out to a student that the mere existence of a scheme structure on the orbit *set* was insufficient to understand the motivation for a categorical quotient.  I then realized I did not know how to prove my first desired phrase: "Since every set can be the scheme of some ring,..."

So I figured someone here might have thought through this before.  Here is my question (as in the title):

> Given a set $S$, does there exist a commutative ring $R$ with identity so that the underlying set of $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ is bijective to $S$?

Every finite set is bijective to the zeros of a polynomial and so that should handle finite sets.  $\mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$ handles the countable case, and affine space over $\mathbb{C}$ gives us an example that is uncountable.  After that I am out of my set theory depth, unfortunately.

I feel like I should be able to use the fact that every set (in ZFC) admits a group structure, to some avail, but I don't see how exactly. Maybe [turn your set into an abelian group](https://mathoverflow.net/q/89877/12218), then group ring, then quotient field and then consider affine space with respect to that field?

Of course maybe this general set-theoretic statement answers the question in the affirmative abstractly: https://mathoverflow.net/a/89878/12218.  However, I would personally feel better with explicit examples/constructions.

Regardless, I suspect the answer is yes and not very interesting.  But perhaps a more interesting question is this:

> Given a set $S$, does there exist an *interesting* commutative ring $R$ with identity so that the underlying set of $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ is bijective to $S$?

If my suspicions are right, then "interesting" here should not mean smooth or normal, but should mean something like "with as bad of a singularity as you want" (some kind of "Murphy's Law" condition).  But to keep the second question more flexible, let's leave it vague for now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a [field of arbitrary infinite cardinality](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1296889/29145); let $K$ be its algebraic closure (which has the same cardinality) and consider Spec(K[X]), which has the same cardinality plus one, i.e. the same cardinality.

Comment: Thanks!  I suspected something like that would work.  I don't know why I didn't just think to look for "fields of arbitrary cardinality" (instead of try to construct them using groups!). I will hold off accepting for now to see if the second question gets any interesting responses. (+1)