# Is it provable in $\mathsf{ZF}$ that there is a group structure on any set $X$?

Tags: gr.group-theory, set-theory

Given a set $X$ is it provable in $\mathsf{ZF}$ that there is a binary operation $\ast: X\times X\to X$ such that $(X,\ast)$ is a group?

Comment: No, as this is equivcalent to AC. See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/12973/does-every-non-empty-set-admit-a-group-structure-in-zf This is thus a duplicate.

Comment: Oh - it is a duplicate. I'm sorry.

Comment: And in any case, you need to assume $X$ is nonempty!