# Does every finite poset have a rigid endomorphism?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, order-theory, semigroups-and-monoids, posets

[Crossposted](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3839902/660) on Mathematics.

In this post, an order-preserving self-map of a poset $X$ will be called an **endomorphism** of $X$, and such an endomorphism $f$ will be called **rigid** if the only automorphism of $X$ which commutes with $f$ is the identity of $X$.

The question is in the title:

> Does every finite poset have a rigid endomorphism?

Every poset of cardinality at most $9$ has a rigid endomorphism.

I wrote a proof of this statement in a separate text. Since links tend to break over time I am including several links to this text:

[pdf file](http://www.iecl.univ-lorraine.fr/%7EPierre-Yves.Gaillard/Rigid_endo_poset_mo/repmo.pdf) --- [tex  file](http://www.iecl.univ-lorraine.fr/%7EPierre-Yves.Gaillard/Rigid_endo_poset_mo/repmo.tex) --- [Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/tczwvzwyqgjc) --- [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1RP1v4kbIZ4iMo0xSjybcgeKtBRVnRcsd?usp=sharing) --- [Mediafire](http://www.mediafire.com/folder/3dityd6zt35rd/Rigid_endo_poset_mo).

In the first version of this question I put the proof in the post itself. But I realized that there was a mistake, and that the post was too long. So I rewrote the proof (hoping that it is correct now), and added links to the new version.

Comment: related (while distinct) to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/358057/for-what-sets-x-do-there-exist-a-pair-of-functions-from-x-to-x-with-the-id, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/359660/centralizer-of-a-single-element-in-the-monoid-of-self-maps-of-a-set

Comment: This looks like a very interesting question (although the wall of text is a bit intimidating- I wish MO had a way of putting stuff inside spoiler tags). But one naive question: do you have a counter-example for *infinite* posets (where I think everything still makes perfect sense)?

Comment: Note that the question is whether the monoid $M$ of endomorphisms of every finite poset satisfies the purely monoid-wise property: $$\exists g\in M:\forall h,k\in M: (hk=kh=1 \text{ and } hg=gh) \Rightarrow h=1.$$

Comment: @SamHopkins- Thanks! No I don't have a counterexample for infinite posets, but I'm very interested in the infinite case as well. I thought it was natural to concentrate first on the finite case.

Comment: Any chain is the image of an endomorphism, so if you can find a chain which isn't fixed by any nontrivial automorphism you're done. (I have no intuition for whether this should be expected to exist in general, but many highly symmetric posets I can think of have this property, eg. any maximal chain in a boolean lattice.)

Comment: To pedantically correct myself, I meant any *nonempty* chain.

Comment: @lambda - Thanks a lot! Looks very interesting!  If I understand correctly you're saying that if $C$ is a maximal chain in a boolean lattice, then $C$ isn't fixed by any nontrivial automorphism. Could you give me an argument or a reference?

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard The boolean lattice $B_n$ consists of subsets of $\{1, \dots, n\}$ and its automorphism group is $S_n$ acting in the obvious way. A maximal chain looks like $\{X_0, X_1, \dots, X_n\}$ where $X_{i+1}$ is obtained by adding a single element to $X_i$. Any element of $S_n$ that fixes both $X_i$ and $X_{i+1}$ must therefore fix this new element, so an automorphism that fixes the whole chain is the identity.